# Accessability of native sensors in Nativescript

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, native

I am the decision of choosing to implement an app in either Nativescript (Cross platform IOS/Android) or doing a 'real' native app with java/swift accordingly.

Discarding the obvious 1 codebase vs 2 codebase discussion, I am uncertain of the limitations of Nativescript, if any.

The main concern lies in the app's heavy demand for sensor data. I have to use a lot of the phone sensors in the app. Sensors like the [android sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview).

I get mostly what Nativescript does. But the question is, **will chosing Nativescript impact either the accessibility of sensors or the overall performance considering the app's heavy demand for native sensor data?**

I've found several plugins (like this [accelerometer plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-accelerometer)) and I am worried I would need a plugin for each sensor and maybe there will be a missing plugin for some of the sensors. Should this be concern?

Comment: There will be no limitation to accessing any of the sensors. As you mentioned there is the accelerometer plugin and there are a few others. However, depending on the sensor you might have to write some of your logic to those APIs which shouldn't be too challenging if you're considering going with java/swift .

Here is something I've worked on recently where I needed the heart rate sensor on a WearOS app, this is not a production project at the moment, but it is planned to be released eventually https://github.com/Max-Mobility/permobil-wear/blob/master/app/pages/home/home-view-model.ts#L239

Comment: So if I access `android.hardware.SensorEventListener` - How do i access specific sensor data. Say I want to access the environmental sensors and retrieve data from `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE`. [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment)

Comment: A sensor listener is how you'll access the data. If you look a little farther down in that sample link provided you'll end up seeing how to access a sensor using the `SensorManager` [see here](https://github.com/Max-Mobility/permobil-wear/blob/master/app/pages/home/home-view-model.ts#L269) and the listener provides `onSensorChanged` which is accessed [here](https://github.com/Max-Mobility/permobil-wear/blob/master/app/pages/home/home-view-model.ts#L241) and I use the values for the HEART RATE. So other sensors will follow the same approach.

Comment: Thanks very good answer, I would accept if you post as an actual answer. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no limitation to accessing any of the sensors. As you mentioned there is the accelerometer plugin and there are a few others. However, depending on the sensor you might have to write some of your logic to those APIs which shouldn't be too challenging if you're considering going with java/swift . [Here](https://github.com/Max-Mobility/permobil-wear/blob/master/app/pages/home/home-view-model.ts#L239) is something I've worked on recently where I needed the heart rate sensor on a WearOS app, this is not a production project at the moment, but it is planned to be released eventually.

As mentioned in the comments to the OP: You will end up using the Sensor Listener to access the data which is returned in the `onSensorChanged` event.

The following code is how to access the Heart Rate sensor on a device.

First, get the device Sensor Manager:

Import/require the `application` module from NS so you can access the Android activity in the sample below

`import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application';`

```
  const activity: android.app.Activity =
    application.android.startActivity ||
    application.android.foregroundActivity;
  const mSensorManager = activity.getSystemService(
    android.content.Context.SENSOR_SERVICE
  ) as android.hardware.SensorManager;
```

Then create our listener:

```
const myHrListener = new android.hardware.SensorEventListener({
      onAccuracyChanged: (sensor, accuracy) => {},
      onSensorChanged: event => {
        console.log(event.values[0]);
        const HR = event.values[0].toString().split('.')[0];
        // HR is the BPM from the sensor here
      }
    });
```

Then we need to get the sensor:

```
const mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
    android.hardware.Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE
  );
```

Finally, we register the listener:

```
const didRegListener = mSensorManager.registerListener(
    myHrListener,
    mHeartRateSensor,
    android.hardware.SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
  );
```

The `registerListener` method returns a boolean so you can do a check if the boolean returned is `true` which means the listener was successful in registering and you'll get data when the sensor provides it in the `onSensorChanged` event.