# How to reference com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.SENSORS_API from nativescript?

Tags: android, nativescript, google-fit

I am trying to reference the Fitness.SENSOR_API as documented (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/Fitness.html#SENSORS_API).

In java I import

```
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
```

and reference it like

```
Fitness.SENSORS_API
```

but this doesn't seem to work in nativescript (referencing it as `com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.SENSORS_API`).

I've logged the value :

```
console.log('fitness native module:', 
com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness); //Fitness is undefined
```

The same is true for other classes in the `com.google.android.gms.fitness` package for example `com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessOptions` as referenced here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessOptions.Builder

Overall, Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
  googleApiClient = new com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
    .addApi(com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.SENSORS_API)
    .addApi(com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.HISTORY_API)
    .addApi(com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.RECORDING_API)
    .addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read')
    .addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write')
    .addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read')
    .build();
```

I do have

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
}
```

in my App_Resources/Android/app.gradle file.

Am I missing something? Do I need to extend or implement some class? Why is Fitness undefined?

My overall goal is to follow these docs (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) and connect to google fitness API

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136683/accessability-of-native-sensors-in-nativescript however I cannot find any nativescript docs on how to access sensors

Comment: We have the [Java to JS marshalling](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) docs which covers the generic syntax you have to follow while converting your Java code into JS. We may need something more than just **this doesn't seem to work in nativescript**, what issue exactly you are facing, you are unable to refer the the native package or not sure how to create an instance of sensor manager? Please be more specific.

Comment: Ya sorry, didn't include a specific error. com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness is always undefined.

Comment: @Manoj really its both, I am unable to refer to the native package, and I cannot find any nativescript documentation about sensor manager (something I didn't know existed until digging into sensor implementations in others packages).

Comment: If may be undefined if dependencies are not installed, did you double check that with a clean build.

Comment: That did it @Manoj, clean and build. While it shouldn't surprise me, it does. Simply because I know it was inspecting/running app.gradle file. Apparently it wasn't laying down the jars or something though. Thanks! Submit as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a clean build to make sure the dependencies are installed properly, accessing the package might return undefined only in such cases.

```
tns platform clean android
```